# In general terms: what is the difference between a handler and a function?

Tags: javascript, handler

From this answer ([What is a handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195357/what-is-a-handler)) I understand that a handler is:

> A handler is a routine/function/method which is specialized in a certain type of data or focused on certain special tasks.

But then I'm asking myself: why not replace the word handler with the word function? What's the difference? The only difference I can tell is that functions do not need to have arguments, which means they do not need to be focused on a certain type of data. And some functions -- without arguments -- are not focused on specialized tasks.

But other than that, what is the difference between a handler and a function?

Some more background:

I find the concept of handler difficult to understand still (it could be because I'm Dutch and there is not a word for it in Dutch according to Google Translate). Checking out the definition helps a bit but not fully.
[image]

Comment: A function is a function. A handler is a function that runs when an event fires. Edit: I see that the linked question mentions other types of handlers, but 99% of the time I use "handler" for "event handler".

Comment: "why not replace the word handler with the word function" — Why talk about cars instead of vehicles? Why talk about dogs instead of animals? Why talk about animals instead of collections of atoms?

Comment: An ordinary function is something you invoke. A handler (or callback) is something someone else invokes.

Comment: Quentin, good point. I didn't see it as clearly, hence the (slightly) provocative question. Especially the cars instead of vehicles part makes it clear to me. It also makes it clear that I don't understand the difference well enough.

Comment: Just don't ask about the difference between an "event listener" and an "event handler".

Comment: @Alohci Someone alredy did XD https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725241/whats-the-difference-between-event-listeners-handlers-in-java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A handler is simply a more specific term.  What's the difference between a fruit and an apple?

All handlers in JS are functions, but not all functions are handlers.  It's a way of being more precise in your terms.  If I say "a function", I could be referring to any function.  If I say "a handler", then I'm referring specifically to a function which is intended to respond to some event that is occurring, usually asynchronously like a mouse click or in Express a request being processed.

Answer (score 5):

Handlers are indeed just functions. Handlers are functions that have the intended behaviour of being called right after an event is fired, for example when an `img` is clicked or when you scroll past a certain element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:
You have a button in a web page, then you press the button, you will have the button HANDLER fires, but a handler is non other than a function that is used to handles an event.

Imagine an onclick event in html, it will call a function, that function is the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Handlers are functions that are called in response to some sort of **actions/events**
whereas, a function is what we call from our code.

In most cases, a handler receives  an argument describing what sort of event fired it.

Generally, It is just a function but the cause for which it is called makes it different.